# Documenting members of members in C# XML-Comments

Tags: c#, xml-comments

How do you document members of members in C# XML-Comments with the `<see cref=".."` tag?

I'm trying to document them the same way as type members, but it's giving me the warning "XML comment has cref attribute '...' that could not be resolved"

Here's the documentation comment in question:

```cs
/// <exception cref="ArgumentException">Thrown if <paramref name="namelistInstance"/> is not an instance of <see cref="Parent.UnderlyingType"/></exception>
```

Where `Parent` is a member of the class this comment is in, and `UnderlyingType` is a member of `Parent`.

A shortened version of the code:

```cs
public class Class1
{
    public Class2 Parent;

    /// <summary><see cref="Parent.UnderlyingType"/></summary>
    public void Method() {}
}

public class Class2
{
    public Type UnderlyingType;
}
```

Comment: So basically you want to show the Parent and Basetype in your cref?

Comment: No, I want to show a member of the member Parent.

Comment: It soundsl like this is what you want. Please edit your question. Make us understand what is `Parent` , `UnderlyingType`? Show some code maybe. What you are saying is a bit abstract. At least to me.